# Русификация убунту 11,10

Tags: ubuntu

Была убунту 11,04. Обновил до 10,10. Вся русификация слетела. Как теперь русифицировать убунту? раньше был выбор языка системы при загрузке. Счас такого нет. Что делать?
Языки все установлены. Теперь как их применить?

Answer (score 1):

system - administration - languages
выбрать русский, система скачает и установит пакеты через инет, после перезагрузки сенанса пользователя появится русский

Comment: Это все сделал в том то и дело что должен был появиться русский, но он не появляется ((((((

Comment: И как Вам 11.10?

Comment: оформление оригинальное (красиво) но все перемешано и непривычно. Совет - не ставить.

Comment: Мое мнение - получилось нечто отвратительное. А самое гнусное - что нельзя поставить GNOME 2.

Comment: Не знаю как вас, а меня все устраивает...

Comment: Счастливый

Comment: прошу прощения.. может не в тему, но спрошу. чем *nix-овая ось лучше винды для простого обывателя, товарищи *nix-оиды? Чем обусловлен выбор не в пользу винды?

Comment: слишком обширная тема для комментариев. лучше вынести в отдельный вопрос. а лучше не выносить ради избежания холливара

Comment: Виталий, для простого обывателя всё одинаково. Ну, может быть nix-овую ось установить и настроить чуть-чуть посложнее.

Comment: о, только заметил - у вас стояло 11.04 а теперь - 10.10... это опечатка, я надеюсь?..
ЗЫЖ ставлю на тестовую машину обновление до 11.10, самолично проверю как будет..

Comment: Я вчера обновился, никаких проблем обнаружено не было...